# Boost on OSX via Homebrew

Tags: macos, boost, homebrew

I try to install boost using homebrew, and when i try, this happens:

```bash
admin:~ Admin$ brew install boost
Warning: No available formula with the name "boost".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Specifing version doesnt help either:

````bash
```bash
admin:~ Admin$ brew install boost@1.58
Warning: No available formula with the name "boost@1.58".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
````

Answer (score 1):

you seemed to join a WiiU Homebrew discord for help, but imma still try to help you with your issue.

Does `brew install boost@1.79` work for you?

If it still returns the same Issue, please try following things:

1. `brew update` after that, try installing boost again.
2. (Only do if #1 didnt work) `brew update-reset`
   after that try installing boost again.
   [Note: this will destroy all your uncommitted or committed changes in any Homebrew repository]
3. (do this if the other 2 failed) `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout -- Formula/boost.rb` followed by trying to install boost again.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core; brew update` fixed it!